# How to exclude a js file from a view- asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, view, reference

I'm developing an asp.net mvc application in which I use a _Layout file to contain all references of js files and css file. But I have only one view which I need to exclude a js file from it's references. What I can do is I dont put this file on _Layout and manually put it on all views except the view mentioned above. But I think it's too cumbersome. Is there any better approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the necessary (page specific) js files in each view which needs them. You should include all common js (*Ex :jQuery,bootstrap etc* ) files in Layout.

When you include page specific js files in views, make sure you do that in the scripts section

```
@section Scripts
{
  <script src="~/js/pageSepcificScript.js"></script>
}
```

Assuming you have a section called Scripts definied in your layout

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```